# MS SQL 2012 (Want to Transpose the data)

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have the data as below

[image]

and want the output as

```
Name        Check In Date   Check Out Date  Check In Time   Check Out Time
Employee 1  20/11/2016      21/11/2016      03:52:15 PM     12:08:50 AM
Employee 1  21/11/2016      22/11/2016      03:45:37 PM     12:14:25 AM
Employee 1  22/11/2016      23/11/2016      03:41:34 PM     12:04:53 AM
```

I tried using case when condition but not getting the output properly.
Kindly help

Regards
Michael

Comment: Only one check in/check out per day?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you want by using a window function.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tt') is not null drop table #tt

create table #tt (name varchar(45), [status] varchar(16), [Date] varchar(16), [Time] varchar(16))

insert into #tt (name, [status], [date], [time]) values

('Employee 1','Check In','20/11/2016','03:52:15 PM'),
('Employee 1','Check Out','21/11/2016','12:08:50 AM'),
('Employee 1','Check In','21/11/2016','03:45:37 PM'),
('Employee 1','Check Out','22/11/2016','12:14:25 PM'),
('Employee 1','Check In','22/11/2016','03:41:34 PM'),
('Employee 1','Check Out','23/11/2016','12:04:53 PM')


;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Name] order by convert(datetime,[Date] + ' ' + convert(varchar(8),cast([time] as time)),103)) as rownum
        from #tt)


select
    ci.Name,
    ci.[Date] as CheckInDate,
    ci.[Time] as CheckInTime,
    co.[Date] as CheckOutDate,
    co.[Time] as CheckOutTime
from
    cte ci
    inner join cte co on
    co.rownum = ci.rownum + 1
where ci.status = 'Check In'


--Results
Name        CheckInDate CheckInTime CheckOutDate CheckOutTime
Employee 1  20/11/2016  03:52:15 PM 21/11/2016   12:08:50 AM
Employee 1  21/11/2016  03:45:37 PM 22/11/2016   12:14:25 PM
Employee 1  22/11/2016  03:41:34 PM 23/11/2016   12:04:53 PM
```

Answer (score -1):

You question title says "MS SQL 2012", but you have used the "sql-server-2008" tag. This solution will work in both. You will still need to format the dates and times if you need them exactly as you have shown.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Test

SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check In' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/20/2016 3:52:15 PM') AS DateTime
INTO #Test
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check Out' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/21/2016 12:08:50 AM') AS DateTime
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check In' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/21/2016 03:45:37 PM') AS DateTime
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check Out' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/22/2016 12:14:25 AM') AS DateTime
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check In' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/22/2016 03:41:34 PM') AS DateTime
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check Out' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/23/2016 12:04:53 AM') AS DateTime
UNION
SELECT 'Employee 1' AS Name,
'Check In' AS Type,
CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/23/2016 03:41:34 PM') AS DateTime

;
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime),
Name, Type, DateTime
FROM #Test
)
SELECT cte.Name, 
CONVERT(DATE, cte.DateTime) AS CheckInDate,
CONVERT(DATE, nxt.DateTime) AS CheckOutDate,
CONVERT(TIME, cte.DateTime) AS CheckInTime,
CONVERT(TIME, nxt.DateTime)  AS CheckOutTime
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE nxt ON nxt.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
WHERE cte.Type = 'Check In'
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you could use the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) functions. The foundation and explanation for this approach can be found [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/).

Comment: I am curious as to the reason for the down vote. My answer produces the core of what is being asked leaving basic formatting to the OP.

Comment: Greetings.... I would require help now. I have another set of records where there are multiple Check In and Check Out with same day and different day. Could you please help